# Oracle SQL - adding in two union queries

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I have to queries on which I am applying a union function.

```
  select item, loc, qty from rms_transfer
  union
  select item, loc, qty from sim_transfer
```

wherever item and loc are same in both the queries, the qty of both the queries should add up in in the final result.

How do we achieve that ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Comment: grouping worked! and its giving correct result.

Comment: There is a general flaw in using 'union' here, because it skips rows from the second query that are already part of the first one. You have to use a 'union all' for this. The needed grouping is already mentioned within the answers so I skip it here.

Comment: Are item + loc unique in the two tables or can I find several rows for an item + loc in one of the tables?

Answer (score 4):

I think you want `union all`, not `union`:

```
select item, loc, qty from rms_transfer;
union all
select item, loc, qty from sim_transfer;
```

`union` removes duplicates.  So, if you want to keep all the original rows, then use `union all`.

If you want the values on the same row, then you can use a post-aggregation:

```
select item, loc, sum(qty)
from (select item, loc, qty from rms_transfer;
      union all
      select item, loc, qty from sim_transfer
     ) il
group by item, loc
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT item, loc, SUM(qty) AS qty
FROM (
  SELECT item, loc, qty FROM rms_transfer
  union
  SELECT item, loc, qty FROM sim_transfer) AS t
GROUP BY item, loc
```

Same `item, loc` pairs will be grouped together and their corresponding quantities will be summed up.

Comment: `union` will remove duplicate rows between the two tables. So they won't be counted twice which is - I think - what Imran wants

Comment: Great answer and combined with union all instead of simple union, solved my challenge.